# Why is the fnSettings() saying it is not a function in the following code and is there a way around it?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to take data from a table and show/hide rows depending on the id.

```
var txnfilterbox = function(table, tabID) 
{
  if (table) 
    {

      var filtervalue = $('#filterText').val();
      if((filtervalue != undefined)&&(filtervalue.length > 0))
        {
          var tableData = table.fnSettings().aoData;
          for (var index = 0; index < tableData.length; index++)
            { 
             var rowData = tableData[index]._aData;
             if (filtervalue === rowData.id)
             {   
                rowData.show();
             }
             else
             {
                rowData.hide();
             }
       }
      }
   }   
};
```

Comment: where do you expect this `fnSettings` property to come from?

Comment: How are you passing the table to txnfilterbox?

Comment: @ Pointy - I am trying to understand that.  I assumed the fnSettings is a function that can be called from a table/nested table.  I am not sure what it should return though?

Comment: @Baltruks - This is mostly the handler of the text box in the HTML.  After entering anything in the box it calls this function to show/hide based on a filter (textbox).